# postgres: schema does not exist when creating a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

Could you please advise why when trying to create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  doc.bgp_communities (

    i             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    comm_name     TEXT NOT NULL,
    comm_value    TEXT NOT NULL,
    label         TEXT NOT NULL,
    used_as       TEXT NOT NULL,
        modified_on   TIMESTAMPZ DEFAULT NOW(),

    UNIQUE        ( comm_value ),
    CHECK         ( (comm_value SIMILAR TO '%:%') OR (comm_value SIMILAR TO '%:%:%') ),
    CHECK         ( used_as IN ('bgp-customer','destination','dtv-peer','free-peer','generic','infrastructure','origin','private-peer','public-peer','traffic-eng','voip-peer') )

) ;
```

Before that I have created the schemas as follows:

```
ip_spotlight-# CREATE SCHEMA doc
ip_spotlight-# CREATE SCHEMA net
ip_spotlight-# ALTER DATABASE ip_spotlight SET search_path TO doc,net
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR:  schema "doc" does not exist
```

Could you please advise what I am doing wrong ?

PS: my user "app" is configured like:

```
app          | Superuser, No inheritance, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

**EDIT**

```
app@[local]:5432 ip_spotlight# CREATE SCHEMA doc ;
CREATE SCHEMA
Time: 1.492 ms
app@[local]:5432* ip_spotlight# CREATE SCHEMA net ;
CREATE SCHEMA
Time: 0.641 ms
app@[local]:5432* ip_spotlight# ALTER DATABASE ip_spotlight SET search_path TO doc,net ;
ALTER DATABASE
Time: 1.036 ms

# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  doc.bgp_communities (
ip_spotlight(# i             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
ip_spotlight(# comm_name     TEXT NOT NULL,
ip_spotlight(# comm_value    TEXT NOT NULL,
ip_spotlight(# label         TEXT NOT NULL,
ip_spotlight(# used_as       TEXT NOT NULL,
ip_spotlight(# modified_on   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
ip_spotlight(# UNIQUE        ( comm_value ),
ip_spotlight(# CHECK         ( (comm_value SIMILAR TO '%:%') OR (comm_value SIMILAR TO '%:%:%') ),
ip_spotlight(# CHECK         ( used_as IN ('bgp-customer','destination','dtv-peer','free-peer','generic','infrastructure','origin','private-peer','public-peer','traffic-eng','voip-peer') )
ip_spotlight(# ) ;
ERROR:  schema "doc" does not exist
Time: 0.686 ms
app@[local]:5432! ip_spotlight# \dn
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
app@[local]:5432! ip_spotlight#
```

Comment: ```ip_spotlight-# CREATE SCHEMA doc
ip_spotlight-# CREATE SCHEMA net
ip_spotlight-# ALTER DATABASE ip_spotlight SET search_path TO doc,net``` need ';' at each command end, to be ```ip_spotlight-# CREATE SCHEMA doc;
ip_spotlight-# CREATE SCHEMA net;
ip_spotlight-# ALTER DATABASE ip_spotlight SET search_path TO doc,net;```

Comment: Can't reproduce your error using superuser. BTW `alter database ... set ...;` does not affects current session. You need to reconnect to get it or execute `set ...;` just after `alter database ... set ...;`

Comment: Do you run the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement in a transaction? If yes, then you are expected to `COMMIT` that transaction, as in PostgreSQL, the DDL statements (also) take part in the transaction. (The space between your statements may imply that you are actually running 2 separate transactions, is it so?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed semi colon at the end of commands, so you probably did not create any schema:

```
ip_spotlight-# CREATE SCHEMA doc
ip_spotlight-# CREATE SCHEMA net
ip_spotlight-# ALTER DATABASE ip_spotlight SET search_path TO doc,net
```

should look:

```
t=# CREATE SCHEMA doc;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# CREATE SCHEMA net;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# ALTER DATABASE ip_spotlight SET search_path TO doc,net;
ALTER DATABASE
```

Comment: Thanks @VaoTsun for looking into it. That is an improvement for sure. But still am getting the same error. Do you have a guess what could be wrong ?

Comment: see "EDIT" above

Comment: had to do it as 'postgres' user :)